# How do I make a Record in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, records, counting

How do I make a counting Record in MySQL?

Comment: Welcome to `Stackoverlow`. Unfortunately we only speak English here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Oke, sorry my friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to count the numbers of rows in MySQL, you would simply use `COUNT(*)`. Take a look at the official documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html).

The query would look like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table;
```